# KEDA Error: Got empty response for: external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, horizontal-pod-autoscaling, keda

I am getting below error after installing keda in my k8s cluster and created some scaled object...

whatever command i am running EG: " kubectl get pods" i am getting response with below error message..

How to get rid of below error message.

E0125 11:45:32.766448     316 memcache.go:255] couldn't get resource list for external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: Got empty response for: external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1

Comment: It is a recent known issue. You can follow these 2 links to get updates on the problem [KEDA issue](https://github.com/kedacore/keda/issues/4008) - [custom-metrics-apiserver
 issue](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/custom-metrics-apiserver/issues/146)

Answer (score 5):

This error is from `client-go` when there are no resources available in `external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1` here in client-go, it gets all ServerGroups.
When KEDA is not installed then external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1 is not part of ServerGroups and hence its not called and therefore no issue.

But when KEDA is installed then it creates an ApiService

```
$ kubectl get apiservice | grep keda-metrics
v1beta1.external.metrics.k8s.io        keda/keda-metrics-apiserver   True        20m
```

But it doesn't create any external.metrics.k8s.io resources

```
$ kubectl get --raw /apis/external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1 | jq .
{
  "kind": "APIResourceList",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "groupVersion": "external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1",
  "resources": []
}
```

Since there are no resources, client-go throws an error.

The workaround is registering a dummy resource in the empty resource group.

Refer to this [Github](https://github.com/kubeshop/botkube/issues/829) link for more detailed information.

Comment: Can you please provide an example on how to register a dummy resource so we can at least hide these errors?

Comment: I found an issue in KEDA Github where there is a [comment, which includes such a dummy manifest](https://github.com/kedacore/keda/issues/4224#issuecomment-1426749781), this works for me.